# Can I use a more restrictive key with Jekyll Algolia?

Tags: jekyll, algolia, api-key

I am building my Jekyll site with Algolia search.

[The documentation](https://community.algolia.com/jekyll-algolia/getting-started.html) about jekyll-algolia says the admin key must be provided in the environment variable `ALGOLIA_API_KEY`.

However, [another page](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys/#default-api-keys) about API key security says

> Your admin API key is the mo**st sensit**ive key: it provides full control of all your indices and data. The admin API key should always be kept secure. D**o NOT** release it to anybody or d**o NOT** use it in any application, and always create a new key that will be more restrictive. This API key should almost exclusively be used to generate other - more limited - API Keys that will then be used to search and perform indexing operations.

Reading the second page, I'm trying to create a more restrictive key for use with `jekyll-algolia` in CI builds of my Jekyll website:

> [image]

However I still get complaints from `bundle exec jekyll algolia`:

```
ibug@ubuntu:~/iBug.github.io$ ALGOLIA_API_KEY="0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef" bundle exec jekyll algolia
Configuration file: /home/wsl/iBug.github.io/_config.yml
Processing site...
         AutoPages: Disabled/Not configured in site.config.

        Pagination: Complete, processed 1 pagination page(s)
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
   GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.
Extracting records...
Updating records in index iBug_website...
Records to delete: 428
Records to add:    420
 [✗ Error] Invalid credentials

 The jekyll-algolia plugin could not connect to your application ID using the
 API key your provided.

 Make sure your API key has access to your 14DZKASAEJ application.

 You can find your API key in your Algolia dashboard here:
    https://www.algolia.com/licensing

ibug@ubuntu:~/iBug.github.io$ echo $?
1
```

How should I do that? Or must I provide the admin key in CI environments?

Comment: Hi iBug, Can you tell me how to finally solve this issue? I met the same question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum API key ACLs required to allow indexing with jekyll-algolia are `deleteIndex`, `addObject`, `deleteObject` and 'editSettings`.

If one of those ACLs is not set you get an error like this :

> [jekyll-algolia] Error:
>   403: Cannot PUT to
>   https://APP_ID.algolia.net/1/indexes/your_folder/settings:
>   {"message":"Method not allowed with this API key","status":403} (403)

In your case, the error message indicates that your application ID is not connected with the API_KEY you provide.

Check your application ID in your Algolia dashboard, and verify that you have a correct `algolia.application_id` entry in your _config.yml.

If you provide the right application_id and one of her API key, it must work, otherwise it's an Algolia problem.

Comment: I have added all ACLs and `bundle exec jekyll algolia` still complains, as can be seen in my question.

Comment: Sorry, for this sunday mornig answer ;-). I've edited my answer.

Comment: @DavidJacquel I checked my code, I indeed have the correct setting for search_only_api and admin_api, but I still met the same issue. Do you know how to fix it? The error of my repository is https://github.com/Jingnan-Jia/Jingnan-Jia.github.io/actions/runs/3238012303/jobs/5305741818